Invalid assignment error in Godot when trying to assign a Quaternion?
In Godot, I'm getting the error  "Invalid assignment of key or property 'basis' with a value of type 'Quaternion' on a base object of type 'Transform3D'." from the following function:
    func _orient_character_to_direction(direction: Vector3, delta: float) -> void:
        var left_axis = -local_gravity.cross(direction)
        var rotation_basis := Basis(left_axis, -local_gravity, direction).orthonormalized()
        _model.transform.basis = _model.transform.basis.get_rotation_quaternion().slerp(rotation_basis, delta * rotation_speed)

I'm following a "tutorial" made for an older version of Godot, and some things do not transfer over exactly. However, I'm unsure why this particular error is occurring, and no one else seemed to be dealing with it.
Much to my own confusion, despite that this code is in GDScript, I'm getting this error:

E 0:00:00:0458   testplayer.gd:50 @ _orient_character_to_direction(): Basis [X: (0, 0, 0), Y: (0, 0, 0), Z: (0, 0, 0)] must be normalized in order to be casted to a Quaternion. Use get_rotation_quaternion() or call orthonormalized() if the Basis contains linearly independent vectors.
<C++ Error>    Condition "!is_rotation()" is true. Returning: Quaternion()
<C++ Source>   core/math/basis.cpp:725 @ get_quaternion()
  testplayer.gd:50 @ _orient_character_to_direction()
testplayer.gd:25 @ _integrate_forces()

Per that error, I attempted to call orthonormalized() on both ends of the _model.transform.basis = _model.transform.basis.get_rotation_quaternion().slerp(rotation_basis, delta * rotation_speed) assignment, but it was either an invalid call (using it after the quarternion) or it did nothing and the error persisted, depending on where I called it (I tried everywhere, even where it made no sense). I also tried calling normalized() on the quaternion to no success whatsoever.
The tutorial I'm following can be found here with the particular function with the error at 2:49.
Note: I'm not great at math and this is my first time using quaternions, so if this is a very simple error, I apologize.

the error is telling you all you need. i do not clearly understand your efforts. please post minimal reproducible example.
